# Initialize a java object within scala class

Tags: java, scala

I want to initialize a java object within scala class, so this works:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
   new Foo
}
```

But this one doesn't work:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    new Foo("Hello")
}
```

My question is, how I can pass arguments to a java object declared inside a scala class?

Comment: Why does it not work? Do you get an error? If yes, then what is the exact error message? What does the Java class look like?

Comment: scala can new java object directly...show us the `Foo` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct, You can check it by the next one code:

```
import java.io.File

def main(args: Array[String]) {
  new File(".")
}
```

Java class `File` takes argument from the scala. You definitely have problem with the class `Foo`. Check if the class correct and if you have a correct class version of the `Foo` in your class path